# Google app engine gives 404 to my spring boot rest api app

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have a pure API Spring Boot App with CORSFilter.
When I deploy the app on google app engine, the following screen comes:

[image: Deploy Sreen]

However, the URL gives me this:

[image: URL Screen]

My complete project code [is here at GitHUB](https://github.com/abhishek-anand13/gcp.git).

The `SMSService.java` might give an error while compiling since I had to remove the AWS keys in order to make it public and they are asking me to take it down.

Comment: If your application is working fine on localhost but giving 404 on App Engine, then add ServletInitializer.java if missing. While creating new Spring Boot project, ServletInitializer is automatically generated.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a url hadler to your `app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: this field is required, but ignored
```

And, what directory are you deploying from?  You have `app.yaml`s in both of these:

`/gcp`

`gcp/src/main/appengine/`

**Update:**

In `MainController.java`, add a url handler for `/`:

```
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
```

Comment: i have added the handlers you described. I am truing to deploy from /gcp directory. it still leaves me with 404 not found. also, i have tried both ways to deploy, mvn:appengine deploy and gcloud app deploy, no help

Comment: It's still giving a 404. Could you give me your email ID or any other mode of communication? I think I will have to talk to you directly and resolve this at the earliest

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have deployed my spring rest application to app engine flex and was successul but I cannot access the endpoints.

Comment: What's the exact issue that you are facing. I was able to solve it. I had to rewrite pom.xml and it worked.

Comment: Adding handler url worked for me, thanks!